# Weibo API auth error

Tags: python, authentication, get, token, weibo

I started to write a project for Sina Weibo and got a problem from the start.
When I make a get request to API:

> http://api.t.sina.com.cn/statuses/public_timeline.json?source=App_key&count=5

I get an error of authentication such as:
{"request":"/statuses/public_timeline.json","error_code":"403","error":"40070:Insufficient app permissions!"}

or another request and answer:

> https://api.weibo.com/2/statuses/user_timeline.json?source=Appkey&trim_user=1&count=100&screen_name=michael

{"error":"applications over the unaudited use restrictions!","error_code":21321,"request":"/2/statuses/user_timeline.json"}

Can someone help me to make this request work?
I just don't het If I need to send token somehow or secret-key.. I am new at development and would be glad if someone answers.

Answer (score 2):

Probably to late, but for future uses. Weibo requires all request to be OAuth2 authenticated. So before using that you need to give permissions and generate access tokens. It's common practice. Services like twitter provide smaller limits also for unauthenticated users, to ease developer live, however that's not the case with weibo :(

If you are working with weibo I highly recommend this article -> 
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/